# Aligning ones of a vector to LSBs

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, verilog, system-verilog

I'm looking for an algebraic solution (gates and adders) to align the '1' bits of a vector to the LSB's.
For example:

```
11001001 will transform to: 00001111
1000 will transform to: 0001
1100 will transform to 0011.
```

I achieved the above but with a custom HDL function that's quite complex (non algebraic) and will probably have poor timing performance. A LUT is another option - but not if the vector is long.
So can this be done algebraically ?

Comment: post your HDL function and we'll see if we can improve it

Comment: You need to "popcount" your input and feed the result into LUT. Alternatively you can implement something similar to a [Sorting Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network)

Comment: As I wrote - a LUT solution is inappropriate because it doesn't scale up well for long inputs (I need this to be synthesizable for long input lengths). And I already have a working solution in the form of a custom HDL function. What I'm searching for is a simpler alternative using boolean algebra...something like - "invert the input, then add one, then xor with the original, flip the bits from right to left - and this is the result :-)".

Comment: LUT is appropriate if you do popcount as I said (same as the countones in the accepted answer). This will require LUT size same as the width of your input, which is definitely sizeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply

```
out = (32'd1 << $countones(in)) - 32'd1;
```

Note: increase `32` to the size of your vector.

Comment: Great! Exactly!
Should one expect synthesis support for $countones (modern FPGA/ ASIC tools) ?

Comment: They should. But if yours doesn't, it is a simple function to write yourself.

Comment: Just checked - with Vivado 2019.1 $countones is unsupported for synthesis. But as you said, it can easily be worked around with a custom function.